# Showing a symmetric bilinear form is nondegenerate

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, semi-riemannian-geometry

I wan to show that the symmetric bilinear form given by
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
     g:  T_pSL_2(\mathbb{R}) \times T_pSL_2(\mathbb{R})   & \to \mathbb{R}, \\ 
        \bigg{(}
            \begin{pmatrix}
            a & b  \\
            c & d \\ 
            \end{pmatrix}, 
            \begin{pmatrix}
            w & x  \\
            y & z \\ 
            \end{pmatrix} 
        \bigg{)}  & \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(az + wd -( by+ xc)).
\end{split}
\label{metric}
\end{align}
is nondegenerate for all $p\in SL_2(\mathbb{R}).$
This is the restriction of the symmetric bilinear form on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ which can be shown to be nondegenerate.
I know that I need to show that $g(v,w) =0$ for all $w \in T_pSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ implies $v =0$ but have no idea how to do this!

Comment: Do you know that a typical matrix $X$ of $T_pSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by "trace$(p^{-1}X)=0$" ?

Comment: Yes but I am unsure what to do with this.

Comment: How do you define what you call **"the"** symmetric bilinear form on M2(R) ? Article **"the"** doesn't look appropriate because there is another classical bilinear form which is $trace(A^TB)=aw+cy+bx+dz$

Comment: It is defined the same way on $M_2(\mathbb(R)),$  this is simply the restriction of the scalar product to $SL_2(\mathbb(R)$ which I now need to show is also non degenerate on $T_pSL_2(\mathbb{R}) \times T_p SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: I just realized that your bilinear form is associated with quadratic form "$\det(A)=ad-bc$''

Comment: You probably have to re-write it using permutation/multiplaction matrixes. So far, I can provide you that your bilinear form is given by $g(A,B)=\frac{1}{2}tr(A (JB)^T)$, where $(JB)^T=\begin{pmatrix} z &-x \\ -y & w \end{pmatrix}$. So now you might wanna figure out the correct multiplicatio/Permutation matrices which will end up becoming $J$ and then use properties of the trace to figure out the rest. It is just a guess though.